# Area of a portion of annulus

Tags: integration, geometry

**Problem**

I have an annulus delimited by two circles of radius $r_1$ and $r_2$, $r_1<r_2$.
I take an angular portion of it, of size $\Delta \theta$, whose surface is $S_{tot}=\frac{\Delta \theta}{2} (r_2^2 - r_1^2)$.

I now draw a segment from the lower-left corner of this portion to its upper right corner, which is of length $h$.
The situation is recapitulated in the sketch below. I am only interested in the case where the red segment does not cross the inner circle.

My question is: what is the area of the green portion ?

**What I tried**

- I tried a first approach, by parametrising in cylindrical coordinates the red segments, from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=\Delta\theta$, and assuming $h(\theta)= r_1 + (r_2-r_1)\frac{\theta}{\Delta\theta}$. Computing $S=\int_{0}^{\Delta\theta} \int_{r_1}^{h(\theta)} r dr d\theta$ is then easily done, however the result is very wrong (checked against a numerical discretisation of the portion, using the Shoelace's algorithm}.
  This is obviously due to the fact that my assumption on $h$ is wrong, $h$ in not linear is $\theta$.
- I then tried reparametrising as a function of $\eta \in[0,1]$ the curvilinear coordinate along the red segment. This yields, in the cartesian system $(x,y)$ centered at the center of both circle:$$P(\theta) =[h(\theta)\sin(\theta), h(\theta)\cos(\theta)]$$ and the coordinates of $P$ are truly linear in $\eta(\theta)$ this time: $$P(\eta(\theta))=[\eta r_2 \sin(\Delta\theta), r_1 + \eta(r_2 \cos(\Delta\theta)-r_1)].$$
  Manipulating both expressions of $P$ yields
  $$\tan(\theta(\eta)) = \tan(\Delta\theta) + \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{(1-\eta)r_1}{\eta r_2 \cos(\Delta\theta)}}$$, from which I can derive a complex formula for $\dfrac{d\eta}{d\theta}$:
  $$\dfrac{d\eta}{d \theta} = \dfrac{r_1 r_2 \dfrac{\sin(\Delta \theta)}{\sin^2(\theta)}}{\left[ r_2 \cos(\Delta\theta)\left(-1 + \dfrac{\tan(\Delta \theta)}{\tan(\theta)} \right) + r_1 \right]^2}$$
  Using it to compute
  $$ S=\int_{0}^{\Delta\theta} \int_{r_1}^{h(\theta)} r dr d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\Delta\theta} \left(h(\eta(\theta))^2 - r_1^2\right) \dfrac{d\eta}{d\theta} d\theta$$
  seems far too complex to me...
  Similarly, expression $h(\theta)$ and plugging it back in the original integral yields an expression which I can't manage to integrate;
- Intuitively, I tried the guess $S = S_{tot} \dfrac{r_1}{r_1 + r_2}$, and I've shown numerically that this is exact to 99% for all values of interest of $\Delta \theta$. However, I am still curious as to what the exact formula is.

Thank you for your help !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area of the triangle formed by the red line and the radii of the two circles that have been depicted is $\dfrac12\cdot (\text{ product of two adjacent sides})\cdot(\text{sine of the angle between them}) = \dfrac12 r_1r_2\sin(\Delta\theta).$

Removing the area of the sector of the smaller circle enclosed by the triangle gives us $$\text{Area of S} = \dfrac12 r_1r_2\sin(\Delta\theta) - \dfrac12 r_1^2\Delta\theta.$$
which tends to $\dfrac12r_1(r_2 -  r_1)\Delta\theta$ as $\Delta\theta$ goes to $0$.

Comment: Oh yes indeed, I totally missed that simple way of decomposing the problem... Thank you for clearing that ! Quite ashamed actually !

Comment: Actually, the area of the triangle is $r_1 r_2 \sin(\Delta \theta) /2$, not $r_1 r_2\sin(2\Delta\theta) / 2$.

Comment: Ah, I saw $\theta$ marked as the half-angle and assumed it was $\Delta\theta$. I'll fix that